# Cookie Handling at Request and Response Level in CefSharp

Tags: cookies, cefsharp, setcookie

How can we intersept (1) the outgoing request cookies present inside "Cookie" header item, and (2) incoming response cookies present inside "Set-Cookie" header item to add new, modify existing and delete?

The requirement is to manage cookies at request runtime (at onBeforeResourceLoad and onRespons event levels).

Comment: https://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_IRequestHandler.htm

Comment: But it does not allow me to share response headers and cookies. I have tried it several times.

Comment: What do you mean by "share", exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, "change" not 'share'.

Comment: Modifying the response is not currently supported. https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2785 You can filter out cookies using https://cefsharp.github.io/api/118.6.x/html/T_CefSharp_Handler_CookieAccessFilter.htm

Comment: Can cookie.Name or cookie.Value changed under "CanSaveCookie" has an impact/change on response cookie saved. @amaitland

Comment: No, you cannot change cookies in `ICookieAccessFilter`